# Cannot get param from route with regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following regex `'(.*)/:id/(.*/)?add-relation/:type'` for a React Router path which would like to work for the following example urls. The part (.*/)? is to catch optional words in the url like `/preview` and `/tasks`.

```
http://localhost:3000/ab/invoices/665/add-relation/invoice
http://localhost:3000/cm/company/665/add-relation/company
http://localhost:3000/ab/invoices/665/preview/add-relation/invoice 
http://localhost:3000/ab/invoices/665/tasks/add-relation/invoice 
http://localhost:3000/cm/company/665/preview/add-relation/company
```

The problem I have is that I cannot get the `id` when I have the above optional words.

For example in the url below
`http://localhost:3000/ab/invoices/665/add-relation/invoice`

[image]

I have the `id` and `type` but when the url includes one of the optional words, like this one: `http://localhost:3000/ab/invoices/665/preview/add-relation/invoice` I cannot get the right id:

[image]

How should I change the regex, so I can get the right `id`?

Comment: You can use `useParams` which will return a proper object with all params, you need not try manual regex.

Comment: Shouldn't your id be 665 in your example. `431` is coming out of nowhere.

Comment: @Andy these are two separate url-s with different id-s. Different examples but in both cases I need the numeric id 431 or 665 but not preview.

Comment: @Rajdeep Debnath useParams returns the same output. For the id I receive preview which is not what I want.

Comment: `invoices\/(\d+)`? and the id will be the second index of the `match` array.

Comment: @vaklinzi then there must be issue with the `Route path` setup. Please share that.

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath It works perfectly fine for http://localhost:3000/ab/invoices/665/add-relation/invoice, the problem is only when I am trying to rich a url with the optional words.

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by being more specific what can be in the first part:

```
'(.*)/(invoices|orders|customers)/:id/(.*/)?add-relation/:type'
```

[image]

Every ( ) makes a separate group, so by adding `(invoices|orders|customers)`, the id stays separate from the first param.